# Oracle: how to get percent of total by a query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query and its result is very unexpected to me:

```
select stato, (count(1) *100) / sum(1)
from LOG_BONIFICA
group by stato;
```

it returns 100 for all rows. Should it be different ?

Comment: specify column name in count() and sum()..

Comment: @Gik25:just try `select stato, count(1) ,sum(1)` in your query ,then you'll got to know why you're getting the 100 for each rows.And can you tell us what you'll expect from count(1) and sum(1)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`count(1)` is equal to `sum(1)` in your case.

Try something like this:

```
18:39:36 SYSTEM@dwal> ed
Wrote file S:\\tools\buffer.sql

  1  select owner,
  2         count(*) group_cnt,
  3         sum(count(*)) over() total_cnt,
  4         round(100*(count(*) / sum(count(*)) over ()),2) perc
  5    from dba_objects
  6   group by owner
  7*  order by 4 desc
18:39:57 SYSTEM@dwal> /

OWNER                           GROUP_CNT  TOTAL_CNT       PERC
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ----------
SYS                                 31609      59064      53.52
PUBLIC                              24144      59064      40.88
XDB                                  1660      59064       2.81
SYSTEM                                597      59064       1.01
WMSYS                                 332      59064        .56
EXFSYS                                312      59064        .53
IRKAZDATA                             158      59064        .27
STRMADMIN                              92      59064        .16
DBSNMP                                 55      59064        .09
RI                                     25      59064        .04
PASS                                   16      59064        .03
POTS                                   19      59064        .03
TI                                     11      59064        .02
STRMODS                                11      59064        .02
OUTLN                                  10      59064        .02
APPQOSSYS                               5      59064        .01
ORACLE_OCM                              8      59064        .01

17 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.16
```

**update**: or even simplier with ratio_to_report

```
18:53:36 SYSTEM@dwal> ed
Wrote file S:\\tools\buffer.sql

  1  select owner,
  2         round(100*ratio_to_report(count(*)) over (), 2) perc
  3    from dba_objects
  4   group by owner
  5*  order by 2 desc
18:54:03 SYSTEM@dwal> /

OWNER                                PERC
------------------------------ ----------
SYS                                 53.52
PUBLIC                              40.88
XDB                                  2.81
SYSTEM                               1.01
WMSYS                                 .56
EXFSYS                                .53
IRKAZDATA                             .27
STRMADMIN                             .16
DBSNMP                                .09
RI                                    .04
PASS                                  .03
POTS                                  .03
TI                                    .02
STRMODS                               .02
OUTLN                                 .02
APPQOSSYS                             .01
ORACLE_OCM                            .01

17 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.20
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you referring to the following?
You need to find the total some separately.

- Reference [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26703/12)

Table:

```
ID  NAME    AMOUNT  STATE
1   john    1000    fl
2   jane    5000    ga
3   james   2000    ca
4   tom     6000    ga
5   tim     8000    fl
6   jim     2000    ga
7   kate    8000    fl
8   jack    3000    tx
```

Results 1:

```
STATE   SUM(AMOUNT)
ca      2000
fl      17000
ga      13000
tx      3000
```

Final Query :

```
select t1.state, concat(
  round(((sum(t1.amount)/t2.total))*100,2),
'%') as pct
from t1, 
(select sum(amount) as total from t1) as t2
group by t1.state
;
```

Results:

```
   STATE    COUNT(T1.ID)    SUM(T1.AMOUNT)  TOTAL   PCT
   ca       1               2000           35000    5.71%
   fl       3               17000          35000    48.57%
   ga       3               13000          35000    37.14%
   tx       1               3000           35000    8.57%
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [ratio_to_report](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions124.htm) analytic function:

```
SELECT STATO, 
    COUNT(1) STATO_COUNT, 
    RATIO_TO_REPORT(COUNT(1)) OVER() * 100 STATO_PERCENT
FROM LOG_BONIFICA
GROUP BY STATO
```

so you don't need to calculate total row count and ratio yourself.