# Percentage of code usage

Tags: sql, oracle

I have lookup table (COLORS)

```
COLOR_ID | COLOR_NAME | USAGE
=========+============+======
1        | BLUE       |
2        | RED        |
3        | WHITE      |
```

and data table

```
PROD_ID | COLOR_ID
========+=========
1012    | 1
2036    | 1
3645    | 2
```

I need SQL which will calculate the percentage of colors used for products and update COLORS table

So the result should be updated table COLORS:

```
COLOR_ID | COLOR_NAME | USAGE
=========+============+======
1        | BLUE       | 66.67
2        | RED        | 33.33
3        | WHITE      |  0.00
```

Problem here is color WHITE (if there's no product in white color) this color has to be updated with 0.00!

Comment: This is just a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` query. Doing a little research will reveal plenty of examples solving similar problems here in SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle: how to get percent of total by a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721093/oracle-how-to-get-percent-of-total-by-a-query)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721093/oracle-how-to-get-percent-of-total-by-a-query

Comment: I'd do a `LEFT JOIN` , to include white in the result.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Problem is when some color is not used at all and it's usage has to be updated with 0.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is different enough from the ones cited as duplicates that it deserves its own attention. Since you only need to execute an `UPDATE` you can also execute an anonymous PL/SQL block. For the data you provided, etsa's solution requires 64 consistent gets. This one requires only 35 consistent gets for the same input data. If you have more data, you can autotrace them both to see which one requires less work under more realistic circumstances.

```
declare
   countall number;
begin
select count(*) into countall from prod_colors;

update colors c set usage = (
  select (count(*) / countall) * 100
  from prod_colors pc
  where pc.color_id = c.color_id
);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
UPDATE COLORS T1 SET (USAGE) = 
 (SELECT CALC FROM (SELECT T1.COLOR_ID, COALESCE(CALC,0) CALC
                    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COLOR_ID FROM COLORS) T1
                    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT COLOR_ID
                                    , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY COLOR_ID) / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) CALC
                               FROM COLORS_DATA) T2 ON T1.COLOR_ID = T2.COLOR_ID
                               ) T3 WHERE T1.COLOR_ID=T3.COLOR_ID)
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT T1.COLOR_ID, COALESCE(CALC,0) CALC
                    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COLOR_ID FROM COLORS) T1
                    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT COLOR_ID
                                    , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY COLOR_ID) / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) CALC
                               FROM COLORS_DATA) T2 ON T1.COLOR_ID = T2.COLOR_ID
                               ) T3 WHERE T1.COLOR_ID=T3.COLOR_ID)
 ;
```

Query without UPDATE:

```
SELECT T1.COLOR_ID, COALESCE(CALC,0) CALC
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT COLOR_ID FROM COLORS) T1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT COLOR_ID
                , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY COLOR_ID) / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) CALC
           FROM COLORS_DATA) T2 ON T1.COLOR_ID = T2.COLOR_ID
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an OUTER JOIN to count the products for each colour. The `RATIO_TO_REPORT()` function calculates the percentage of each colour across the result set:

```
SQL> with cte as (
  2     select c.color_id
  3                , c.color_name
  4                , count(p.product_id) as prod_cnt
  5     from colors c
  6              left outer join products p
  7                     on p.color_id = c.color_id
  8     group by c.color_id
  9                , c.color_name
 10  )
 11  select color_id
 12        , color_name
 13        , ratio_to_report(prod_cnt) over () as usage
 14  from cte
 15  order by color_id;

  COLOR_ID COLOR_NAME                        USAGE
---------- ---------------------------- ----------
         1 BLUE                         .666666667
         2 RED                          .333333333
         3 WHITE                                 0

SQL>
```

> "So the result should be updated table COLORS"

Very poor practice. Every time you amend the PRODUCTS table you have to recalculate the usages for the whole COLORS table. The overhead of maintaining such derivable values will **vastly exceed** the occasional cost of running the query when your users actually need to know the usage percentages.