# Oracle SQL group by rollup and ratio_to_report

Tags: sql, oracle, percentage, rollup

I have a table like this

[image]

I have a query to show the number of vehicles manufactured in each region and the percentage of vehicles manufactured in the region

```
 select  
            COALESCE(Region, 'Total') AS Region,
            count(veh_vin) as "Total Vehicles Manufactured",
            round(ratio_to_report(count(veh_vin)) over(),2) as rr
        from( 
            select 
                case 
                    when substr(veh_vin,1,1) between 'A' and 'C' then 'Africa'
                    when substr(veh_vin,1,1) between 'J' and 'R' then 'Asia' 
                    when substr(veh_vin,1,1) between 'S' and 'Z' then 'Europe'
                    when substr(veh_vin,1,1) between '1' and '5' then 'North America'
                    when substr(veh_vin,1,1) between '6' and '7' then 'Oceania'
                    when substr(veh_vin,1,1) between '8' and '9' then 'South America'
                    else 'Unknown'
                end as Region,
                veh_vin
            from vehicle
        )
        group by ROLLUP(Region)
        order by count(veh_vin), Region;
```

which gives me the following result

[image]

But I want something like this, which exclude the total when calculating the percentage.

[image]

Is it possible to achieve it with ratio_to_report? If not, how could I alter the query?

Comment: I think this might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721093/oracle-how-to-get-percent-of-total-by-a-query

Answer (score 1):

I prefer an explicit calculation.  You can adjust the calculation (either way) for the aggregated row:

```
select coalesce(Region, 'Total') AS Region,
       count(*) as "Total Vehicles Manufactured",
       round(count(*) * 1.0 / sum(case when grouping_id(region) = 0 then count(*) end) over (), 2) as rr
from . . .
```

The same idea doesn't quite work with `ratio_to_report()` -- because it returns `NULL` instead of 1.  But you *could* use:

```
   coalesce(round(ratio_to_report(case when grouping_id(region) = 0 then count(*) end) over(), 2), 1) as rr
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ecf29938120a4ce6021e0b6b2c3c2c9b) is a little db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you so much. Really appreciate it. I feel that I am learning a lot of new stuff here.

Comment: @GordonLinoff While I did not find your answer very illuminating, I found the code in db<>fiddle invaluable.